# How to implement "strictly less than" when setting up constraints in CPLEX Python api?

Tags: python, cplex

I think the character 'L' represents <=, how about strictly less than i.e. '<'?

Comment: You can't use a strict inequality. LP and MIP solvers only support <=.

Comment: Is there some kind of workaround for these inequalities?

Comment: Instead of say `x+y<1` you can formulate `x+y<=0.999`.

Comment: Yea thought of that but one of my variables may take quite small values. May be I should consider restricting the range of my input values in order to avoid variables taking such small values.

Comment: A complicating factor are feasibility tolerances. You may want to loop up what they are.